# In REACT, GET http:/xxxx 401 (Unauthorized)/ (CORS) : For "localhost"

Tags: reactjs, cors, access-token, request-headers

Trying to call the below API by using `axios.get`method. I've bypassed the CORS by using the `Moesif CORS` google extension.

The API required the tokens in order to pull the result by using `POSTMAN`.

Insert the valid tokens: Getting the CORS error although the `CORS` extension is enabled. 
[CORS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yQGw.png)
Without the tokens: Getting the 401 Unauthorized with `CORS` extension enabled as well. 
[401 Unauthorized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrMLh.png)

I'm sort of confused, is it either my token unauthorized issue or the CORS issue here? could someone please advise? However, if I called the other API that does not require the token I'm able to get the result without any issue with the `CORS` extension enabled.

Sharing my example codes here:

```
const tokenStr = 'abc1234'; // example
const config = {
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenStr}` }
};

let dcqoapi = 
"http://quote.dellsvc/v3/quotes?number=" + Quote + "&version=" + Version;

  const calldcqoapi = () => { //assign a variable for a call function
        Axios.get (dcqoapi,config).then(
          (response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })

  };
```

Comment: *I've bypassed the CORS by using the Moesif CORS google extension.* You should never have to do that.

Comment: The issue was resolved via disabling the web security from Chrome, please refer to the below answer.

Comment: That's even worse than using a Google extension! For your own sake and your users', please reconsider your approach.

Comment: @jub0bs this is just for debugging and developing the environment. no putting this to the production or running on the live server yet. How could it impact the user???

Comment: Development mistakes have a funny way of making it to production.

Comment: I might not put my question correctly, believe you are fully misunderstanding it.

Comment: I know this is a very bad practice, but I really couldn't find any way to proceed with my development using localhost without a server yet, I will take your advice and keep it in mind after moving on to the server environment. anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was resolved via disabling the web security from Chrome. Here are the below actions I've taken: [WORKS FOR LOCALHOST]

1. Create a shortcut on your desktop.
2. Right-click on the shortcut and click Properties.
3. Edit the Target property.
4. Set it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:/ChromeDevSession"
5. Open Google chrome (You should see the message "disable-web-security" on top of the page)
6. Run your app
7. Copy your localhost URL and paste it to the Chrome
8. It works perfectly now for calling the API with headers tokens.

By doing the above steps, we had fully bypassed all the security including the CORS. Hence, `Moesift CORS` is no longer required.  
As I'm using POSTMAN for calling the API with the `Headers`.
Some little changes from my codes, instead of putting 'Bearer' and I've removed it.
The 'bearer' is for authorization.
Headers are not considering bearer tokens, it's just a key so we shouldn't enter the 'bearer' for the POSTMAN `headers`.

```
let config = {

  headers: { Authorization: 'PlACE YOUR TOKENS HERE'}

};

let dcqoapi =
"https://quote.dellsvc/v3/quotes?number="+ Quote +"&version=" + Version // set DCQO API

const calldcqoapi = () => { //assign a variable for a call function
    Axios.get (dcqoapi,config).then(
      (response) => {
      console.log(response);
})

};
```

Comment: This is terrible in terms of security, and you'll hit the original problem again anyway when you to deploy to production.

Comment: @jub0bs this works for me in the developing stage, putting this to the test/staging environment would consider another workaround for the CORS. I'm doing all the things on localhost instead of running on the server.

Answer (score -1):

You need to trace HTTP responses more scientifically - using browser tools or a tool such as Charles proxy. Bear in mind that APIs are sometimes poorly implememted and don't return CORS headers correctly.

For an approach, see [Step 15 of my blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/). Do you get response headers to that work for the browser in all of these cases?

- Call API without an access token
- Call API with an invalid access token
- Call API with a valid access token

Comment: The issue was resolved via disabling the web security from Chrome, please refer to my answer...